# Estimate clothes drying time (evaporation)

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, estimation, evaporation

I'm a computer scientist pal, For a University project we are making an app that should estimate your laundry drying time assuming that you're hanging them to dry on a line (either outdoor or indoor) with a huge degree of approximation eh eh...

We have sensors to get Ambient temperature and relative humidity, we have also access to forecast regarding windspeed, atmospheric pressure and eventual precipitation.

As I said, we're allowing a huge degree of approximation thus what I did so far is to assume that we have a single medium size shirt that has **chest=49cm, length=66.5cm**; assuming the shirt has a rectangular shape, it's surface of contact with the air should be: `A=(length*chest)*2=6517cm^2`.

- dry weight = 120g
- wet weight = 320g
- water weight / volume = 200g = 200mL ==> 2*10^(-4) cubic meters

Another big assumption is that knowing the volume of water and the surface of contact with the air, instead of considering the clothes example, we squeeze all the water in a big cylindric bowl that has as Area of the circle, the surface of contact previously calculated. In this way we can use the following formula (that I found online):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epvPGdR11P8 
https://www.cpp.edu/~tknguyen/che313/pdf/chap1-1.pdf

[image]

where:

- C = concentration = P/RT
- Dab = Diffusivity Constant
- ya = mol fraction of water vapour
- Z2 - Z1 = Delta of heigh of water in the container (from h to zero)

I calculated the heigh of the water in the container using the formulas of the volume of the cylinder and the area of the circle:

[image]

then:

[image] 
[image] 
where Pws = water saturation partial pressure

With all this I was able to partially solve all the incognitas of my equation:

[image]

where the red incognitas are the one I haven't figure it out yet.
Please can you help me finding out the values of **Dab and Pws**? **Or suggest a better approach**?

---

### --- **Possible Solution** ---

So I figure out that we can calculate the Diffusivity of the water for a given temperature using the Stokes-Einstain Law:

$D=\frac{kT}{6\pi \mu r}$

where:

- k = Boltzman constant = $1.38E^{-23}\frac{m^2kg}{s^2\cdot K}$
- $\mu$ = water viscosity (see table) : https://wiki.anton-paar.com/en/water/
- r = radius of water molecule = $1.375E^{-10}m$
- T = temperature in kelvin ($C^0+273.15$)

While **pws** can be found here in this table: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-vapor-saturation-pressure-d_599.html

We can substitute the values in the previous formula and also multiply all by the Area (surface) of contact and the molecular weight of the water: $MW_{H_2O}=\text{18.01528g/mol}$

$ N_{a,z}=\frac{\left(\frac{P}{RT}\right)\left(\frac{kT}{6\pi \mu r}\right)}{z_1}\ln \left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{RH\cdot pws}{P}\right)_{air}}{1-\left(\frac{RH\cdot pws}{P}\right)_{clothes}}\right)$

finally:

$Vap.Rate\ =\ N_{a,z}\ \cdot \ A\ \cdot \ MW_{H_2O\ \ }$

**Please can you double check my logic, I'm not a physicist I could be wrong**

Comment: Welcome to Physics! We do have MathJax here to format equations. You can see [the notation page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in [help] for details, if you aren't familiar with it (though it's similar to LaTeX).

Comment: Hi @KyleKanos I didn't know, is it not ok like this?

Comment: It's preferred to use MathJax over images, considering images are susceptible to link rot & not capable of supporting screen readers.